# Alias hash keys ruby

Tags: ruby, parameters, alias

In my class i have

```
@@hashtable = {foo: 10,fooo:20 ...}
```

I can now check the values like this

```
@@hashtable[foo]
```

is there a way to alias it making myself able to call it like this

```
@@hashtable[foos]
```

and get the value of

```
@@hashtable[foo]
```

Comment: So it's two questions inside one? SO is one question at time. Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_method(options)
  'asd' if options[:param1] == :asd
end

def my_other_method(options)
  options[:param1] = :asd if options[:param1] == :asds
  my_method options
end

my_other_method param1: :asds #=> 'asd'
```

Comment: is this the only way? isn't there any alias method like way?

Comment: cuz this means i will be repeating this line for all parameters i am going to input

Comment: no there isn't, but you can always write an helper method